# Value of the object is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, dom-events

I've got a Javascript object where the value is `undefined` when I am console logging it.

Code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($rooms as $room) {
        if(isset($room->room_id) && isset($room->trained))
        {
        echo 'myRooms['.$room->room_id.'] = '. $room->trained.';';    
        ?>

        <?php
    }}
?>

//console.log(myRooms)
var newValues = {}

function changeCheckBox(checkBox)
{
    if(checkBox.checked == true){
        newValues[checkBox.name] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        newValues[checkBox.name] = 0;
    }


}

function submitAction()
{
    for(var i in myRooms)
    {
        console.log(i)
        console.log(myRooms[i])
        console.log(newValues[i])
    }

//    console.log(myRooms)
//    console.log(newValues)

}
```

Any help is welcome, I'm learning Javascript/PHP right now.

Comment: By seeing your code it seems that you didn't create any variable in java-script with name myRooms

Comment: It would be useful if you added the `<script>` and `</script>` tags so it was more obvious what you were doing here

Comment: `$rooms` has value how you expected? Your PHP code `echo` something? What is the output?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you have to declare variable, before using.
For example you must put this before your php code

```
<script>
var myRooms = []; 
</script>
```

Comment: He is trying to do that in the PHP code if you look again

Comment: Probably his cycle doesn't print anything

Comment: @RiggsFolly, He is trying to create new elements of array  `myRooms['.$room->room_id.'] = '. $room->trained.';' `

You can see more here ->
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp 
`var person = [];
person[0] = "John";
person[1] = "Doe";
person[2] = 46;`

Comment: if `$rooms` has only `id` and `trained` he can use `json_ecnode()` instead a loop, the output is different but the information are the same.

Comment: But problem here is that he doesn't declare variable. PHP do that for you, but javascript doesn't. It's "undefined".